# where are the official directx forums?

Tags: directx, msdn, forums

I have been checking around MSDN and Microsoft.com but i can only find Archived forums. Are there any microsoft run forums for DirectX anymore?

Comment: I fear this isn't programming related and is likely to be closed. Do you have a question? Folks here do know a fair bit about DirectX and may be able to help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's here:
http://forums.xna.com/forums/

You will find everything related to XNA, D3D, D3D10, D3D11 etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's also the DirectX-Dev mailing list; go to http://discussms.hosting.lsoft.com/SCRIPTS/WA-MSD.EXE?A0=DIRECTXDEV to subscribe or browse the archives. It's pretty specific to D3D, but if that's what you're interested in there's quite a few experienced and helpful people on the list.

Comment: Best not to ask questions there unless you know your theory.  You'll get a great answer but you won't necessarily understand it ;)

Comment: FYI, DirectXDev has been moved to a Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/directxdev

Answer (score -1):

Check out the DirectX Developer Center community page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/bb896725.aspx